# IOS Swift how can I hide characters pass a certain limit

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, swift3

I have a `UIButton` that is being used as a `label`, the button is inside a `TableView` and it is populated by data that I am getting from `Json` . The way I have it set up is that if a particular row has more than 100 characters then only show the first 100 characters, if the user clicks on the button then I would like to show the rest of the data . My problem is that when I show the first 100 characters I am over-writing the rest of the Post-Message so that when the user clicks on the Button-Post it still shows the first 100 characters instead of the full message . My code will clear things up

```
var Posts = [String]()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     if let post = Stream["post"] as? String {
              // if contains more than 100 show only 100
                                if post.characters.count > 100 {
                                   let startIndex = post.index(post.startIndex, offsetBy: 100)

                                    self.Posts.append(post.substring(to: startIndex).appending("... Read More"))
                                } else {
                 // contains less than 100 characters
                                    print(post.characters.count)
                                    self.Posts.append(post) }
                            }

                      }


  func Post_ShowAll(sender: UIButton) {
        // This is supposed to show the full message
        var post_limit: String = Posts[sender.tag]
         print(post_limit)
        if post_limit.characters.count > 100 {

        let startIndex = post_limit.index(post_limit.startIndex, offsetBy: post_limit.endIndex)

             post_limit.append(post_limit.substring(to: startIndex))
        }

    }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomePageTVC", for: indexPath)

         cell.post.setTitle(Posts[indexPath.row],for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.post.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomePageC.Post_ShowAll(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.post.tag = indexPath.row

        return cell
    }
```

I think that my issue is in the `viewDidLoad` if a **post** has for instance 150 characters then it will fall inside the IF statement and cut it down to 100 characters. Once a user clicks that Post button to ShowAll method it still displays the same 100 characters because the original full data has been overridden . Is there someway that I can only show the first 100 characters and hide the rest ?

Comment: Better you store the original data in somewhere else and if the user press button, append original data to `posts` array and reload particular cell.

Comment: You can use `String(yourString.characteres.prefix(100))` for displaying it